# I don't find the mistake in my RandomForest-classification

Tags: raster, error, random-forest

I am trying to make a RF-classification of aerial-imagery to specify tree-species.
I extracted 3 bands and made a .csv file with columns:

```
band1  band2  band3  x  y  class
```

The `band` columns include the pixel-value of the point which I marked in ArcGIS and copied to the attribute-table.
`x/y` include the coordinates of the points.
`class` includes the class, such as forest, juniper...

The RF reads the .csv and classifies the bands it sees in the rasterstack.
The classifier gives back an image with the classes.

So I mark my code and run it:

A classifier-window shows up, and freezes.
5 Seconds later the console shows an error:

```
 Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'band1' not found
```

---

The problem is unclear. The code is right, but the compiler reacts as if there was a typo when I run the code. But as far as I can see, there is no typo.
`band1`, like `band2` and `band3` are in the pointdata_sw_aug1.csv. It is the 1st column and has no space before or after it (" band1"). Therefore I uploaded the images.
Since my rasters are in tif-format, I recently changed the code because at first is was written by Aaron for img-files:

```
rlist=list.files(getwd(), pattern="img$", full.names=TRUE)
```

to

```
rlist=list.files(getwd(), pattern="tif$", full.names=TRUE)
```

The RandomForest-Package then opens a little "predict" window where it says that 31 steps are left.
It takes 5 seconds till it stops with an error-message:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'band1' not found

It doesn't go on.

---

This should work, but gives me an error:

```
require(sp)
require(rgdal)
require(raster)
require(randomForest)
```

**# Set the working directory**

```
setwd("D:/BA-Workspace/DOP_10/orthophotos_abcd/R/test_run_R")
```

**# Create list of rasters**

```
rlist=list.files(getwd(), pattern="tif$", full.names=TRUE)
```

**# Create raster-stack**

```
rasters = stack(rlist)
```

**# Read Raster Training-Table *.csv**

```
intable = read.csv("D:/BA-Workspace/DOP_10/orthophotos_abcd/R/test_run_R/pointdata_sw_aug1.csv")
```

**# Assign Training-points from Columns**

```
myrf = randomForest(factor(class) ~ band1 + band2 + band3 , data = intable, ntree = 2500)
```

**# Run RandomForest classifier**

```
predict(rasters, myrf, filename="outFileName.img", type="response",
    index=1, na.rm=TRUE, progress="window", overwrite=TRUE)
```

my .csv:
[image]

[image]

As far as I can see there are no mistakes.
Whats wrong here?

Error-message is this (copied from console):

```
require(sp)
require(rgdal)
require(raster)
require(randomForest)


 >setwd("D:/BA-Workspace/DOP_10/orthophotos_abcd/R/test_run_R")


> rlist=list.files(getwd(), pattern="tif$", full.names=TRUE) 
> 

> rasters = stack(rlist)
> 
> intable = read.csv("D:/BA-Workspace/DOP_10/orthophotos_abcd/R/pointdata_sw_aug1.csv")
> 
> myrf = randomForest(factor(class) ~ band1 + band2 + band3 , data = intable, ntree =     2500)
> 
> predict(rasters, myrf, filename="outFileName.img", type="response",
+         index=1, na.rm=TRUE, progress="window", overwrite=TRUE)
**Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'band1' not found**
```

Comment: Try making sure the bands are separate in a single folder and named like so: band1.img, band2.img, band3.img.  Then stack the bands in R.  The band names in the script, csv and rasters need to be the same.

Comment: My images have .tif format, but that's not the problem because the prediction starts.
rasterstack is also created, but then, while the .csv is used to classify, something goes wrong and it stops.
the band names are all the same, as I pointed out above.

Comment: well, this question is still on hold. Is it not clear or did I make a mistake? thanks for the support so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is related to the layer names of your raster stack ('rasters'). Make sure these are the same as in your .csv.
You can get the layer names with names(rasters) 
and set them with names(rasters) <- c("band1", "band2", "band3")

Hope this helps
TimSalabim

Comment: Hi Tim, Welcome to GIS@SE, this would have been better as a comment rather than an answer as it does not provide a specific solution to the question asked. Once you get the response form your suggestions, you may then be able to provide an answer to the question. Cheers.

Comment: well. to be honest, it was the solution. I searched for typos and mistakes in the code, but forgot that my file-names have to fit, too...
Thanks, Tim!